# how to delete the last slash of the url in php

Tags: php

After a header Location, my url looks like this:

```
http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/
```

How can i delete the last `/` out of the url?

here is the code which produces the url with header Location:

```
//do a refresh
$tree = explode('/', $_GET['delete']);
$treeDir = '';
foreach($tree as $dir) {
    if(is_dir($treeDir.$dir) && !empty($dir)) {
        $treeDir .= $dir.'/';
    }   
}
header ("Location: ".'?dir='.$treeDir);
```

Comment: use `rtrim($string, "/")`

Comment: The rtrim() function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this simple thing with the help of a PHP function called [rtrim](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_rtrim.asp).

> The rtrim() function removes whitespace or other predefined characters
>   from the right side of a string.

```
$string = 'http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/';
echo $str = rtrim($string, "/"); //http://example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1
```